# Align ListView's children to top and bottom

Tags: flutter

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to align `ListView's` children like `Column's` `spaceBetween` alignment?

Like in this screenshot:

[image]

Problem that I tried to solve:

In the beginning I had a `Column` widget with 2 children. The `Column's` alignment was set to `spaceBetween`. It was what I wanted, one widget at the top, one at the bottom. But then when I clicked to input to add credentials, the keyboard caused an overflow issue described in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13339). So to fix it, I replaced the `Column` with `ListView`. But now my children widgets are stuck at the top of the screen.

My full `LoginScreen` code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/button.dart';
import '../widgets/input.dart';
import '../widgets/logo.dart';

class LoginScreen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Background(),
          Wrapper(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Background extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          end: Alignment.topCenter,
          colors: [
            Color(0xfff6f6f6),
            Colors.white,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Logo(LogoColor.dummy_black),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: BottomPart(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class BottomPart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Input('User name'),
        Input('Password'),
        Button(
          'Log in',
          onPressed,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onPressed() {}
}
```

Comment: [try this one, this is work well for my problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871024/15241468)

Answer (score 6):

Find a solution. You should wrap your Column in IntrinsicHeight and ConstrainedBox with minHeight.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text('2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using `SizedBox(height:50.0) // or any other value`  in b/w `Logo` widget and `Align`(bottom part).

```
 return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Logo(LogoColor.dummy_black),
        SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/ 3),// you will get value which is 1/3rd part of height of your device screen
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: BottomPart(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Then the space will be fixed height. So if I open my app on a tablet, the bottom part will be at the center of tablet's screen.

Comment: Hmm, Using media query get the height/3 value and use it sizedBox height or divide your scaffold into two parts(containers) using media query which will divide screen depending on its height. On top part add Logo and on bottom part add login form.

Comment: Simplier would be to wrap it in Container, with screen size height and then add Column with spaceBetween property. Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found out soln to this problem. Use Code :`

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        // Your Widget Here
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use ListView's property reverse

```
reverse: true,
```

And then change the order of the ListView children.

Comment: wow, cool solution

Answer (score 0):

you can insert this between logo and Align

```
    Expanded(child: SizedBox(height: 8)),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take out the bottom part from ListView, and put it in the last of Stack's children. Your Wrapper could look like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var bottomHeight = 120.0;//replaced with your BottomPart's height
    return Stack(
      children: [
        ListView(),//your ListView
        Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - bottomHeight,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: bottomHeight,
              child: BottomPart(),
            )
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```